# Surface integral in spherical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Question:

Evaluate the surface integral $\int_SF\cdot dS$ where $F=\langle3x,-z,y \rangle$ and $S$ is the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 4$ in the first octant, with orientation towards the origin.

We thus parametrize our surface as:

$r(u,v)=\langle 4\cos(u)\sin(v), 4\sin(u)\sin(v), 4\cos(v)\rangle$

I am going to skip the details of how to calculate the normal because for a sphere it always follows the same pattern, the normal is:

$\vec n = (-16\cos(u)\sin^2(v), -16\sin(u)\sin^2(v), -16\sin(v)\cos(v))$

We can see this is the origin pointing normal, just as requested and now:

$F\cdot\vec n = -192\cos^2(u)\sin^3(v)$ (verified with wolfram)

Thus our integral becomes:

$\int^{\pi/2}_0 \int^{\pi/2}_0-192\cos^2(u)\sin^3(v) du dv = -32\pi$

All I know is that this solution is wrong, and I am not sure where the mistake is. I am following the theorem:

$\int\int_SF\cdot dS = \int\int_D F(\phi(u,v))\cdot\vec n(u,v) du dv$

Comment: $dS$ is an infinitesimal scalar area. $F\cdot dS$ would be a vector quantity. So the integral over $S$ would be a vector, not a scalar like $-32\pi$. Unless you mean $\cdot$ to be the vector dot product, and $dS$ is supposed to mean $d\vec{n}$, the normal unit vector to $S$?

Comment: This is a scalar integral, so you are correct, we do mean $\cdot$ to be the dot product

Comment: Then why is it written with $F\cdot dS$ as the integrand? $F$ is clearly a vector. But $dS$ is not a vector, so there is no defined dot product between them. You know that your solution is wrong; does that mean that you know what the expected correct answer is?

Comment: I am simply borrowing the notation from my lecture slides, I am sorry if it's confusing but that's the notation I have been taught. And no i do not know what the correct answer is, all I have is software that tells me whether my answer is correct or not.

Comment: Does the software indicate that it is expecting a number as the answer? This notation appears to me to be expecting  vector answer, like <1,1,1>. If you enter a vector answer, does it tell you that it is expecting a numerical answer?

Comment: I can say with 100% confidence the expected answer is a scalar. As a matter of fact, the answer can be interpreted as the flux of a fluid through the area represented by the section of the sphere following the vector field $F$

Comment: Then I would expect the integral to be written $\iint_{S}F\cdot d\vec{n}$, not $\iint_{S}F\cdot dS$. I guess it's just different notation than I am familiar with. If it's flux, I think you want to dot $F$ with a _unit length_ normal vector, which would just be $\frac{1}{4}\langle x,y,z\rangle$. The magnitude of your $\vec{n}$ is $4\sin(v)$ times this. It's like you are weighting the flux contributions near the equator at 100% but the ones near the north pole at 0%, and all times a factor of $4$.

Comment: The magnitude cancels out with the jacobian: 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx
(look right above example 1, they prove the normal doesn't have to be normalized)

Comment: OK, then did you try positive $32\pi$? Maybe its expecting the flux in the opposite direction. If that's not it, I'll think about actually carrying out the integral I think it should be to see if the software accepts it.

Comment: yes I tried both positive and negative

Answer (score 1):

For $\iint_S\langle3x,-z,y\rangle\cdot d\vec{n}$, with orientation toward the origin, I get 
$$\begin{align}
&\iint_S\langle3x,-z,y\rangle\cdot d\vec{n}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\langle12\cos(u)\sin(v),-4\cos(v),4\sin(u)\sin(v)\rangle\cdot-\langle\cos(u)\sin(v),\sin(u)\sin(v),\cos(v)\rangle\,16\sin(v)\,du\,dv\\
&=-192\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(u)\sin^3(v)\,du\,dv\\
&=-192\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(u)\,du\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^3(v)\,dv\\
&=-192\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\\
&=-32\pi
\end{align}$$

which matches your answer. Sometimes there is a bug in the problem code for these software platforms. Is this MyMathLab? WeBWorK? WebAssign? Something else?

Comment: Pretty sure you are using WeBWorK, since I found this problem in its library. (I'm one of the WeBWorK developers.) I examined the code for this problem and it is expecting `-32pi` for your random version. All I can think of is either (1) your instructor has modified the problem from how it comes out the box, and accidentally broke it; (2) your instructor is the original author of the problem, and is using a buggy version that was fixed when it was accepted into the Open Problem Library; (3) you mistyped `-32pi` when you tried that; (4) you entered `-32pi` into some other problems's answer; or

Comment: (5) you entered `-32π` with a unicode pi character instead of typing `pi`. Those are my best guesses, but of course there could be other explanations.

Comment: You are correct, I am using webwork. I typed pi in plain letters as I usually do, so I don';t think it's a unicode problem. I am curious how do you know which question I am doing?

Comment: That second line is why I sometimes very much appreciate vectors notated as column matrices!

Comment: The answer is actually $-4\pi$ we both made a similar mistake, the radius of the circle is 2 not 4

Comment: Ah, doh! Glad you caught it. I searched the library of WeBWorK problems (which I have here on my laptop) for "in the first octant, with" and there were only a few hits. One was clearly the same as the problem you described. I looked at its code and assumed values for the variables according to your version, but made the same mistake about $r$. The problem code basically defines the answer as $-a\cdot r^3\pi/6$, where $a$ is the coefficient of $x$ in the expression for $F$.